# Value of Cell A1 could point to values of different cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I am having difficulty with the following. Cell A1 could have values from 1 to 50. I have a listing on a separate table of different values that 1 to 50 represents. (I.E. `1` equals 1.68) I would like cell B1 to return the correct value from the table when a value (1-50) is entered into cell A1.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: That sounds like the classic use of `VLOOKUP()` to me. Have you tried that? What's the difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

Use [VLOOKUP()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318).

Assuming your lookup table is in H1:I50, you'd put the following in B1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,H1:I150,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

- for only A1 cell:

  ```
  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!D1:E, 2, 0))
  ```

  [image: 0]

  ---
- for array of cells:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, Sheet2!D1:E, 2, 0)))
  ```

  [image]